# Can't reshape to right shape size

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, reshape

### My original dataset is 7049 images(96x96) with following format:

train_x.shape= (7049,)

```
train_x[:3]
0    238 236 237 238 240 240 239 241 241 243 240 23...
1    219 215 204 196 204 211 212 200 180 168 178 19...
2    144 142 159 180 188 188 184 180 167 132 84 59 ...
Name: Image, dtype: object
```

I want to split image-string into 96x96 and get the (7049,96,96) array.
I try this method:

```
def split_reshape(row):
    return np.array(row.split(' ')).reshape(96,96)

result = train_x.apply(split_reshape)
```

Then I still got result.shape=(7049,) 
How to reshape to (7049,96,96) ?

Comment: I'd like to see 3 lines of your CSV file, and also how you're loading your data into the dataframe. You need to fix the _code_ that _loads_ the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo:

Source Series:

```
In [129]: train_X
Out[129]:
0    238 236 237 238 240 240 239 241 241
1    219 215 204 196 204 211 212 200 180
2    144 142 159 180 188 188 184 180 167
Name: 1, dtype: object

In [130]: type(train_X)
Out[130]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [131]: train_X.shape
Out[131]: (3,)
```

Solution:

```
In [132]: X = train_X.str \
                     .split(expand=True) \
                     .astype(np.int16) \
                     .values.reshape(len(train_X), 3, 3)

In [133]: X
Out[133]:
array([[[238, 236, 237],
        [238, 240, 240],
        [239, 241, 241]],

       [[219, 215, 204],
        [196, 204, 211],
        [212, 200, 180]],

       [[144, 142, 159],
        [180, 188, 188],
        [184, 180, 167]]], dtype=int16)

In [134]: X.shape
Out[134]: (3, 3, 3)
```